# Correct way to typset esssup (essential supremum)

Tags: spacing, math-operators

What is the correct way to typeset [essential supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum), with the limits underneath the operator?  My first try was `\operatorname{ess}\sup\limits_{x\in[0, 1]}`, but this puts the `x\in[0, 1]` under the `sup` only.

The best I got was using `\operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{x\in[0, 1]}`, but I'm not sure if `\,` is the correct amount of space.  Is there some way to trick `\limits` to working here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following defines an new math operator with:

- `\DeclareMathOperator{\OperatorCommand}{OperatorName}` and
- `\DeclareMathOperator*{\OperatorCommand}{OperatorName}` if limits are to be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% We use the starred versions since we are interested in using limits.
% You can use \thinspace if you want to use a command. If you want to use more math oriented
% commands you can use \mspace{<length in mu>} like \mspace{2mu}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}

\begin{document}
\[\esssup_{x\in[0, 1]}\]
\end{document}
```

> The `\,` and `\!` commands are the most useful for fine tuning math formulas.

Note that `\thinspace` is the same thing as `\,`.

Spaces which are very useful can be:

- `\thinspace` = `\,`
- `\medspace` = `\:`
- `\thickspace` = `\;`

Negative spaces now:

- `\negthinspace` = `\!`
- `\negmedspace`
- `\negthickspace`

If we get a little bit more technical, in the [amsmath.sty](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.sty), we can find the definitions of the above as:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tmspace}[3]{%
  \ifmmode\mskip#1#2\else\kern#1#3\fi\relax}

\renewcommand{\,}{\tmspace+\thinmuskip{.1667em}}
\let\thinspace\,

\renewcommand{\!}{\tmspace-\thinmuskip{.1667em}}
\let\negthinspace\!

\renewcommand{\:}{\tmspace+\medmuskip{.2222em}}
\let\medspace\:

\newcommand{\negmedspace}{\tmspace-\medmuskip{.2222em}}

\renewcommand{\;}{\tmspace+\thickmuskip{.2777em}}
\let\thickspace\;

\newcommand{\negthickspace}{\tmspace-\thickmuskip{.2777em}}

\newcommand{\mspace}[1]{\mskip#1\relax}
```

Of course, `\mspace{<length>}` can be used for both positive and negative spaces. For example, `\mspace{1mu}` and `\mspace{-1mu}` where `mu` means `math unit`.

Note that `\,` is used extensively even to define `\limsup` command in the `amsmath` package in the following manner:

```
\def\limsup{\qopname\relax m{lim\,sup}}
```

The above can be found in [amsopn.sty](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsopn.sty).

Comment: Note that `\,` and friends are **math spacing** whereas `\thinspace` and co. are **text spacing**, which is a critical distinction (it produces errors otherwise).

Comment: @AlexNelson Hmmm is it? I didn't know that. What errors are you talking about?

Comment: sum was a typo.  It should be sup everywhere.

Comment: There's still `sum` in there.  As far as I know, `ess\Sum` means nothing.  As I said, it was just a typo.

Comment: So what kind of space is `\ ` (backslash-space)?

Comment: `\ ` is an interword space.

Comment: Also, how do I know that `\,` is indeed the kind of space that I want?  It seemed to match, e.g., `\limsup`, but the difference can be subtle, so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @asmeurer See my updated solution and remark.

Comment: @AlexNelson `amsmath` defines `\,` as `\renewcommand{\,}{\tmspace+\thinmuskip{.1667em}}`. This means that `+\thinmuskip` (`\thinmuskip=3mu=3/18em=.1667em`) is used in math mode, `.1667em` in text mode. Furthermore, `amsmath` lets `\thinspace` to `\,`, so they are equal.

Comment: @AlexNelson The command `\,` can be used in both text and math mode, where it has the same behavior. Well, this is not *strictly* true, of which I can give a wonderful proof, but comments are too short to contain it.

Comment: @egreg Beautiful! So we must wait 350 years for this proof.  ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke `\parindent0pt\par\,true\par true\bye`