# Behavior of \, in both text and math mode

Tags: math-mode

> The command `\,` can be used in both text and math mode, where it has
>   the same behavior. Well, this is not strictly true, of which I can
>   give a wonderful proof, but comments are too short to contain it. ---
>   @egreg

The above remark was given by @egreg in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86330/10898) that I posted. Since it is too long for a comment, could someone elaborate on this?

Comment: See item 1 of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/21344)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of `\,` in the kernel:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1304:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{%
   \relax\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\thinspace\fi
}
```

Now we look at `\thinspace`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1315:
\def\thinspace{\kern .16667em }
```

So in text mode a kern is used; a kern is almost like glue, but is never used as a line break point unless it's followed by glue (TeXbook, page 75, end of first dangerous bend), besides not being able to stretch or shrink. So `A\,B` will never be broken across lines, but `A\, B` can be.

Note that `.16667em` is 1/6 of an em (in the current font). Usually `\thinmuskip` is set to `3mu`, so it is 1/6 of an em in the symbol font, which may be the same as the em in the current text font, but not necessarily. Of course, if the value of `\thinmuskip` is changed, the command will give really different results in text and in math mode.

The construction `\mskip\thinmuskip` is primitive. A `\thinmuskip` is used between an operator and an ordinary symbol and in some other cases.

Comment: perhaps it is worthwile to point out that the math mode definition also does not allow a break point, a math skip does not behave like a text skip in that regard. Thus the math mode action of `\,` parallels the text mode also in that regard (and as spaces are ignored in math mode, one would need `$a\allowbreak\,b$` rather.)

Comment: @jfbu Line breaks in math mode are allowed only at penalties (explicit or implicit).

Comment: as you said "`A\,B` will never be broken across lines" I felt that "and (for other reasons) `$A\,B$` will also never be broken across lines" could complement it, the whole question being about comparing the text and math mode actions.

Comment: @jfbu The fact is that it's *obvious* that `\,` isn't a break point in math mode. Basically, only relation and operation symbols are.

Comment: It may be *obvious* for you, I don't know if it was for the OP.