# How to print the “essential supremum” operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I have problem with that:

[image: Math]

How to do that? `\supess` don't exist, I tried with only `{supess}` but same - won't compile :/

This is what I have already: `{supess}\limits_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}`.

Comment: `$\mathop{\mathrm{suppess}}\limits_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}$`

Comment: @Herbert Or rather $\mathop{\mathrm{sup\,ess}}\limits_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 2\pi}$. However package `polski` (OP is a Pole) changes inequalities to the Polish version.

Comment: Alternativity using the `amsmath` package: `$\underset{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}{\mathrm{supess}}$`

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: maybe, I have no idea what `suppess` means.

Comment: @Herbert if I could know :) I have evaluation work - rewriting part of the math manual :D

Comment: @Herbert It is essential supremum, hence a small space between sup and ess.

Comment: @TymoteuszMaciejStępień So please be aware of Polish typographic rules. BTW: some lessons with Zofia Walczak? (Sorry that in public, but there are no private messages).

Comment: Nope - Agnieszka Sibelska (if you want to know about lessons with tex/linux/webdev)

Comment: @TymoteuszStępień I have just seen her files. You need NOT to be aware of Polish typographic rules. :-( I hope that you are not forced to reproduce horrible mistakes from exercises (na przykład Zadanie 3, Zadanie 4 czy Zadanie 6).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86327/15925

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke We done all of this, it's horrible - same as webdev (my passion from primary school, and I have job in this) - I told her it's better ways to do something like this or this, but yeah - she have higher academic degree than me so I just "agree" with that and done what she told us to do. It's end of this exercises so uff. I pass this lessons in her "class" so it's good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use amsmath and `\operatorname`. While `\mathrm` uses normally the same font as the operators, one can be sure that this is true in all math setups. (The star leads to `\limits`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[\operatorname*{sup~ess}_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Variants are to use `sup\,ess`, and the `\leq` can be changed too. If needed a command like `\supess` can be defined with `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Answer (score 14):

You probably want to declare a new math operator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\supess}{sup\,ess}

\begin{document}

\[
\supess_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is more convenient than using `\operatorname*{sup\,ess}` (note that `~` is not the best here), because you may be requested to change the rendering into

[image]

(a notation more commonly used in document written in English), which can be accomplished by just changing one line

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\supess}{ess\,sup}
```

without chasing for all appearances in the document.

Comment: What is the drawback of ~ in that setting? How do the two compare?

Comment: @ClementC. The appearance is non-standard with the larger space between `sup` and `ess`. The thin space is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\mathop{\mathrm{sup~ess}}\limits_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}\]
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Please observe that OP needs different typographic rules.