# LaTeX Error: Command \ng unavailable in encoding OT1

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, sharelatex

Please I have a problem and the situation is very urgent, my bibliography have certain characters and I'm not sure what is the cause of the problem.

I'm using the online editor sharelatex and this error message appears.

please your fast response will really help

```
LaTeX Error: Command \ng unavailable in encoding OT1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1054 

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Thank you

Comment: Just add the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble.

Comment: I assume, you have searched your `*.bib` files for `\ng` and `ŋ`? This might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407742/how-to-print-the-essential-supremum-operator

Comment: Ummm actually no, like I should remove these two characters or what?

Comment: @OlegLobachev I searched for these two characters in the bibliography there is no such characters involved. Is there other characters could cause the problem?!

Answer (score 3):

The solution depends on the TeX engine that's in use. If you use pdfLaTeX, load the package `fontenc` with the option `T1`. If you use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, nothing special needs be done in order for `\ng` to work properly, though loading the `fontspec` package is probably a good idea anyway.

A full MWE (minimum working example)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec} % optional
\else\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec} % optional
\else % assume that pdftex engine is in use
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % optional for "\ng"
\fi\fi

\begin{document}
\ng
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same characters still appears in the bibliography :(((((

Comment: @F505 - Did you perform a full recompile cycle — LaTeX, BibTeX, and latex twice more?

Comment: Actually I'm using sharelatex online editor,I tried to compile with both pdfLatex and xeLatex and both produce these characters.

Comment: is the cause of the problem the existence of some characters in the bibliography?! I'm not really sure and this is confusing me

Comment: I realized that the problem is because if this package \usepackage{arabtex}, I really don't know what to do

Comment: @F505 - I suggest that you post a *new* query, in which you describe your document setup in greater detail, including a mention of the fact that you load the package `arabtex`. In this new query, you should also provide one or two examples of bibliographic entries that are causing you grief. Be sure to mention *how* you construct the formatted bibliography: By hand, with BibTeX (with or without a citation management package such as `natbib`), or with biblatex. The aim should be to post a query that actually generates the problem you wish to fix.

Comment: @F505, I know you said in the other post you don't want to shift to `xelatex` because you find it too slow... But can I suggest you revisit this thought? RTL languages require a lot of hacks in `pdflatex` and it's just so much easier using `xelatex`. You will probably find that the time saved in trying to solve these kind of problems will outweigh any difference in compile time :).